# How do I install JetBrains Rider via snap on Linux Ubuntu 20?

Tags: rider, ubuntu-20.04

I am attempting to install JetBrains Rider on an Ubuntu Linux system using snap.

I use the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install rider --classic
```

It looks like it installs correctly.
I can seem to to figure how to actually start Rider.

How do I run Rider after it's been installed via snap.
Is snap the best way to install?

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=269689

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command `snap run rider` in the terminal and hit enter.

A first time installer will run letting you specify Rider customisation and other defaults.

Subsequently you can enter the command `/snap/bin/rider` in the terminal and hit enter.

Alternatively, create a Rider menu item by running the following command `cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/rider_rider.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

[image]

You will then also have the option to right click and "Add to panel"

---

**Update:** Adding `/snap/bin` to your path (the fact it is missing I suspect is a snap bug) will also fix this issue.

I opened up `~/.bashrc` and added the following line at the bottom `PATH=/snap/bin:$PATH`

Saved and reloaded the file by executing `source .bashrc`

Now I can load rider from any bash terminal by simply entering `rider` and hitting enter.

---

I'm using Debian buster btw.

### References:

https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started#heading--running
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=319827